# Why are FALSE, string '0', number 0 and NULL all equal(==) between each other except null and string 0?

Tags: php, comparison-operators

I was experimenting with empty values in php, and i can't really wrap my head around this comparison issue. I defined variables this:

```
$a = 0;
$b = '0';
$c = false;
$d = null;
```

When i use equivalence operator (==) they are all equal, except variables $b and $d. Can someone please explain me why? I read documentation about type juggling and type casting, but i still can't understand why. False and '0' are equal, false and null are equal, but null and '0' are not equal. There's no logic in it.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php - `Before utilizing these tables, it's important to understand types and their meanings. For example, "42" is a string while 42 is an integer. FALSE is a boolean while "false" is a string.`

Comment: Best way to be safe is to use strict comparison `===`. `==` would cause a lot of issues and make debugging difficult.

Comment: Why should there be no logic behind `$b == null` resulting in `false`? `$b` is not `null` because it contains a string hence not `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. When comparing null and string, PHP converts NULL to an empty string. So "" != "0"